# how to wordwrap a header in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

Using ag-grid, is there a way to split a long header across 2 rows...

A break in the columnDefs headerName: `'Long<br />Header'`
gets me part way there (using dev tools I can see the text has the br), however one of the surrounding elements has a height of 25px; `<div class="ag-header" style="height: 25px;">` which I think causes the second line of the header to not be displayed.

I wondered about using group headers as an interim to get the text split, but longer term (when I need to group) that won't be an option...

Comment: Pls help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65018177/ag-grid-community-infinite-row-model-for-server-side-pagination-community-free/65040658#65040658

Answer (score 20):

Try to add the following to your CSS:

```
.ag-header-cell-label {
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

and add this to your grid options:

```
headerHeight: 48
```

Comment: Looks like only the white-space: normal is needed

Comment: this worked for me but now I am getting some mis-aligned text due to the menu icon. the menu icon on the right bumps the top line to the left. this causes the two line header not to center on top of each other but be off to the left.
Any advice on styling with that?

Comment: `overflow-wrap: break-word;` also helps if you have long single-word headers (e.g. if you are German).

Comment: This option did not work for me with ag-grid@15.0.0. See my answer below for an alternate solution that works in this version.

Comment: Use `white-space: pre` if you want to specify where the line breaks occur.

Comment: In addition to doing this, I needed to set my column widths to hard-coded numbers instead of calling autoSizeColumns() or sizeColumnsToFit().

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518883/react-ag-grid-row-auto-height-doesnt-work

Answer (score 12):

Using ag-grid@15.0.0, only the following solution worked:

```
.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This is one of the first times in my work with css that I have ever really needed to use `!important`.

Comment: Specify the theme class to be more specific, and you should avoid the need for !important. eg.   
   
`.ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
    height: auto;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal;
}
 `   

Another way to be more specific is to apply your own class to the header within your column defs. So there's a couple of ways to avoid the use of !important.

Comment: above solution will help you to split header text.
if I would suggest  use text-overflow and overflow css property
******
.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal !important;
}

****

Answer (score 8):

For me, using the combination of `angular@5.5.1` and `ag-grid@13.3.1`, the following worked:

```
::ng-deep .ag-header-cell-text {            
    text-overflow: clip !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

[::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) is an Angular CSS combinator (directive). This is based on Stian's answer with the difference that in my case, instead of `.ag-header-cell-label`, it worked only with `.ag-header-cell-text`.

In the grid options object you must set the header height:

```
this.testGridOptions = <GridOptions>{
            onGridReady: () => {
                this.testGridOptions.api.setHeaderHeight(75);
                this.testGridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
        };
```

Comment: I'm using ag-grid@15.0.0 and this approach is not working for me.

Comment: I think I figured out an answer. I will post my solution below.

Comment: This worked for me (ag-grid@21.0.1) only if you put the css at the component level.

Comment: ng-deep is required if you are applying the style via an scss file in the component.

Comment: This worked for me, even without the `!important`

Answer (score 6):

For me, none of the above solutions worked. What did work for me was to set the headerHeight (in GridOptions) to your specified height and then add the following:

```
.ag-header-cell-text {
   overflow: visible;
   text-overflow: unset;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

In my case, I did not need to add anything to `.ag-header-cell` wrapper class.

I am using the following versions:

```
"ag-grid-angular": "18.1.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "18.1.1",
```

Answer (score 6):

put this in grid options

headerHeight: 50

in style.css

```
.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
    white-space: normal !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need a line break at a certain position in your header, you can use `white-space: pre` to achieve this. Add this to the CSS (change the theme if you are using a different one):

```
.ag-theme-material .ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

And then add `\n` characters to your header name accordingly. You will also have to make sure that there is sufficient height using `gridApi.setHeaderHeight()` and `gridApi.setGroupHeaderHeight()`

Comment: pre-line is also an option, in my case more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

From v28 of AG Grid this is now natively supported by setting the properties `wrapHeaderText` and `autoHeaderHeight`.

```
const gridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    resizable: true,
    wrapHeaderText: true,
    autoHeaderHeight: true,
  },
};
```

You can play with these properties in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FhBacspJwo1YDxDw?open=main.js)

[image: Auto Header Height]

Answer (score 0):

You can try following css:

```
.ag-header-group-text,
.marginright-xs {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ag-header-cell-label {
   word-break: keep-all;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great [article from the AgGrid blog](https://blog.ag-grid.com/wrapping-column-header-text) on the topic.

While all previous answers are simpler, they all imply having a fixed-height header. This article covers the implementation of the adaptive header - that is, making the header adjust its height based on the size of the wrapped text, even when resizing columns.

In summary, you should do the following:

1. Use a custom header template or component, and set `white-space: normal` on the header cell text element.
2. Implement a function that would calculate the required header height based on the maximum height of the wrapped text elements in all headers.
3. Implement a function that would set the required header height using the previous function and the grid API.
4. Hook the above function up with the table's callbacks: `onFirstDataRendered` and `onColumnResized`, to recalculate header height initially, and then every time any column is resized.