# AG-Grid Angular 6 m Multiple Line header

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am actually trying to create an ag-grid with a 2 Lines of text in Header.

For ex- i have 10 columns having header as 'Name', 'Address', 'DOB' and other details. For 'DOB' i want to display the date format just below 'DOB' in the header itself. so far, i have tried 'DOB
(mm-dd-yyyy)' and some css styles from [how to wordwrap a header in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894190/how-to-wordwrap-a-header-in-ag-grid)  but nothing has worked for me.

is there any option to achieve this without creating custom header components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well,Here is the solution i got

Create one custom component like custom-header

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-custom-header',
template: `
<div>
<div class="customHeaderLabel">{{headerName}}<br>{{subHeaderName}}</div> 
</div>
`
})
export class CustomHeader {
private params: any;
private headerName:string;
private subHeaderName:string;


agInit(params): void {
this.params = params;
this.headerName = params.displayName.split('-')[0];
this.subHeaderName = params.displayName.split('-')[1];
}
}
```

Use this custom component in main component where column defs are declared

And also in main component declare header name as date-(dd-mm-yyyy) (seperate by '-')

Comment: The question specifically says `is there any option to achieve this without creating custom header components?`

Answer (score 0):

For those using ColDefs, try

```
private columnDefinitions: ColDef[] = [
{
    ...,
    headerName: 'My ID',
    headerComponentParams: {
    template:
      '<div class="ag-cell-label-container" role="presentation">' +
      '  <div ref="eLabel" class="ag-header-cell-text" role="presentation">' +
      // the header HTML text
      '    My<br>ID' +
      '  </div>' +
      '</div>'
    }
    ...
}, ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I got the solution , i directly put the html in headername with inline style and it worked.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Can you please share the code piece.

Comment: Its been long, but i guess it was just html code in headername property. probably headerName='<div>date</div><br/><div>another div </div>'

Comment: I'm not able to get this working. Would you be able to provide more detail?